# D3 sort() results in weird unexpected behaviour

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on a motion chart showing the development of certain data points through time by updating the position and size of the corresponding circle on a chart (similar to https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/ ).

Since circles can overlap I need the smallest one to be drawn on top.

In the example this is accomplished by calling `selection.sort()`, but if I do the same (with the newer D3v4) I get an unexpected behaviour. The sort seems to switch the data objects associated to the visual circle object.

Check this fiddle to see. Run it once as it is (without calling `sort(order)` in line 45) - this is the expected behaviour. The y value of each object doesn't change so the circles should move on a horizontal line. Now uncomment line 45 to call the sort on each update and run it again. This time the paths of the circles suddenly cross (because the underlying object is switched).
https://jsfiddle.net/orj1rcy8/1/

The API states `selection.sort() Returns a new selection that contains a copy ...`. I assume this is the problem, however I don't understand at this point how the correct approach would look like.

Comment: Are you sure you shared the correct fiddle?

Comment: You're right, sorry, I corrected the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

You need a key function when you bind your data:

```
.data(dataForKey(keyIndex), function(d){ return d.name})
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7kyvzkwe/

**Long answer**

What happened here is that you were victim of what we call *object constancy*, or, more precisely, not properly setting an object constancy (here is a good reading about it, written by [Mike Bostock](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/)).

The problem is that, in D3, the data is bound to the elements in their order:

> If a key function is not specified, then the first datum in data is assigned to the first selected element, the second datum to the second selected element, and so on.

So, let's see what happened. Your code has three circles, in this order:

1. The smallest circle, r = 3;
2. The medium circle, r = 10;
3. The largest circle, r = 15.

The data is appended in that above-mentioned order. But then, when you do `sort(order)`:

```
function order(a, b){
    return radius(b) - radius(a);
}
```

You sort the elements, and now you have:

1. The largest circle, r = 15;
2. The medium circle, r = 10;
3. The smaller circle, r = 3.

And then comes the problem: next time you run the `next` function and bind the new data, you're binding the data to DOM elements in that new order. That is, the data regarding the smallest circle is being bound to the largest circle in the DOM. Using the names of your elements, you're binding the data regarding `item1` to the `item3` in the DOM (given you have 3 elements, the only one always receiving the correct data is `item2`).

You can understand this better in the next fiddle. In this next fiddle, I'm using exactly your code, uncommenting the `sort` function. But, unlike your original code, here I'm changing the order of the data, so we have the largest circle first, then the medium, then the smallest:

```
[{name:"item1", x:1, y:2, z:15},
{name:"item2", x:1, y:4, z:10},
{name:"item3", x:1, y:6, z:3}];
```

You can see that, even calling `sort`, the circles stay in their positions. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9p1tL43j/

That happens because the next time the function `next` runs, the data for the smallest circle is bound to the smallest circle (in the DOM), and so on...

Thus, in a nutshell, you need a *key function* if you want to keep the object constancy. A [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data):

> ... may be specified to control which datum is assigned to which element, replacing the default join-by-index.

Comment: Even though I am yet to encounter a problem like this (because I've never had a sort + join use case before), thanks for the very enlightening answer! I'll definitely keep this in mind if I'm using sort + data joins in the future. +1 :)